# Parsing JSON File using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "inventory": [ 
        ...
    ],
    "services": {
        "M": 2,
        "Moneypenny": 2,
        "intelligence": [
            {
                "missions": [
                    ...
                ]
            },
            {
                "missions": [
                    ...
                ]
            }
        ],
        "time": 25
    }
}
```

I want to parse the Services in the JSON.
I managed to parse the Inventory by getting it using JsonArray.
This is how I do the Services part:

```
JsonElement MinstancesJson = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("services").get("M");
int Minstances = MinstancesJson.getAsInt();
```

But my program crashes in the first line.

Comment: "But my program crashes in the first line" -> What is the error?

Comment: @RobAu Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:732)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:698)
 at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:48)
 at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseReader(JsonParser.java:85)
 at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:110)
 at bgu.spl.mics.application.App.main(App.java:44)

Comment: Try splitting the line and store intermediate objects, then you'll find exaclt which method class causes the error

Comment: @RobAu it crashes here: JsonObject jsonObj = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("services");

Comment: then split that line in multiple lines with variable assignments. You'll find which method causes the error.

Comment: make p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("services");  to  p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject("services");

Comment: @RobAu it crashes here:  JsonObject jsonObj = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject();

Comment: @Nitika can't do that it says: Expected 0 arguments but found 1

Comment: post whole code

Comment: @miljon JsonArray inventoryListJson = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("inventory"); JsonObject jsonObj = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject j = jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("services");
            JsonElement MinstancesJson = j.get("M");
            int Minstances = MinstancesJson.getAsInt();

Comment: what is file here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code which is running perfectly in my system:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

public class EntityName {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("others//entity-name.json");
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(f));
        JsonElement element = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("services").get("M");
        System.out.println(element.getAsInt());
    }

}
```

Here entity-name.json contains given json.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a class for each item in the json.

So, you would create the class `Inventory`, the class `Services`, the class `Intelligence` and the class `Missions`.

For example, the class `Services` will be like this:

```
public class Services {

    int m;
    int moneyPenny;
    List<Intelligence> intelligenceList;
    int time;

    //Constructor, getter and setter

}
```

Note that `intelligenceList` is a list of `Intelligente` objects.

After all, using the `com.google.gson.Gson` library, you can parse your json through the `fromJson` method. In this way, you will have a `Inventory` object.